# Matching ids and intersecting array values in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Consider the following collection:

```
{ "_id": "red", "c": [1, 1, 2, 3] }
{ "_id": "green", "c": [4] }
{ "_id": "blue", "c": [1, 2, 4] }
```

Given an unknown number of strings (ids) I want to get the documents that match those strings but also have a common number in "c".
For example, for the input of `["red", "blue"]` I'd get `[1, 2]` but for the input of  `["red", "green"]` I'd get `[]`.

I think I need to use [$setIntersection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/#exp._S_setIntersection) but I couldn't get the result I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$setIntersection` is between two arrays. It will not work for input with unknown number of strings.

You can use below aggregation pipeline.

The below query `$unwind`s  `c` array and count all `c` array entries in the first `$group` followed by `$match` to keep duplicate entries. The second `$group` to `$push` the duplicate entries into `common` array.

Update: Add `$setUnion` `c` array with `[]` set to remove duplicates.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    {$match:{_id:{$in:["red", "blue"]}}}, 
    {$project:{c:{$setUnion:["$c",[]]}}},
    {$unwind:"$c"}, 
    {$group:{_id:"$c", count:{$sum:1}}}, 
    {$match:{count:{$gt:1}}}, 
    {$group:{_id:null, common:{$push:"$_id"}}}
)
```

Comment: Updated answer. Add `$setUnion` `c` array with `[]` set to remove duplicates.

Comment: Excellent! I initially wrote that it fails with duplicates, then I went to see if I can remove the duplicates in my data, but your update solves it!

Comment: Also, is there a way to update ```$gt``` to support any size of input array? for example, for ```["red", "blue", "yellow"]``` the count should be ```$gt: 2```

Comment: You can use $project with $size to calculate the input array size and use it in match stage or you can do it on client side and pass it directly to the match filter. https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/size/